# 404 not found error with axios using React, Express and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I have a practice simple web application that I am working on, where I have defined the Router paths as below in the `React` front-end:

```
<Router>
      <div className="container">
      <Navbar />
      <br/>

      <Route path="/user" component={CreateUser} />
      </div>
    </Router>
```

The component where I have added the `axios` request looks like this:

```
onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const user = {
      username: this.state.username
    }

    console.log(user);

    axios.post('http://localhost:3000/users/add', user)
      .then(res => console.log(res.data));

    this.setState({
      username: ''
    })
  }
```

and my routes look like this:

```
router.route('/add').post((req, res) => {
  const username = req.body.username;

  const newUser = new User({username});

  newUser.save()
    .then(() => res.json('User added!'))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});
```

and this is how I have imported them in the server:

```
const exercisesRouter = require('./routes/exercises');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

app.use('/exercises', exercisesRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
```

However, I am getting this error:

[image]

I don't understand where the issue could be since all paths seem okay, can anyone please help with this, this is my first time with `React` and the `Express` framework. I have used Insomnia to test my API and it feels like its not an `axios` issues but more of the API endpoint issue, but I can't figure out where exactly. Thank you, would be glad for any help!

Comment: Does it hit your API route ? It seems you're unable to save the user data. Have you check ed the API response in the postman. It will help you segregate the issue is in the API or from where the calls is being made.

Comment: I haven't checked with Postman but I have checked it with Insomnia, I think its not hitting the API at all, it says cannot post in Insomnia as well.

Comment: I think you should change the way you are creating route: `router.post('/add', (req, res)=> {})`. Also, you can check is your server running on same port '3000'.

Comment: Its still giving me the same error! And yes the server is running on port 3000 bc I can see the webpage running, and the process is running as well.